# Prevent CSS3 Blinking background color overrides

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-animations

I have a table with *n* rows that is created programmatically, and on each row I programmatically add a class to distinct `odd` rows from `even` rows. Some of this rows have a "special" content that needs to be highlighted, and to do that I'm using a blinking background on the row:

[**See a Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UCbW8/2/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class='blink odd'>
        <td>first row, very important</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>second row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='odd'>
        <td>third row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fourth row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='odd'>
        <td>fifth row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='blink'>
        <td>sixth row, also important</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'blink' {
    0% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
    50% { background: none }
    100% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
}
.blink {
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;   
}
table tr.odd{
    background: gray;
}
```

The problem I have is that the *blinking* rows are fading the background *from red-to white-to red*, while I'd like them to switch background *from red > to the current row background color*

for example: on odd rows, the BG should change between red and gray. On even rows, the BG should change between red and (in this case) no-BG.

Is this possible to achieve with css without setting two keyframes (one for odd and one for even rows)?

Thank you

Comment: so you want to change the important item's bg to change from present color to red and alternate!1? dats it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually declaring the `background` so it overrides your grey one, so don't declare the backgrounds at all..

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    50% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UCbW8/3/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/UCbW8/5/) *(Added `-moz` and standard properties)*

> Note: I've changed `.odd` class to `table tr:nth-child(odd)` which
>   will save you declaring classes by your self in HTML, because if you can opt for animations than am sure you are not looking to support legacy browsers. If you are using for some specific reason than you can stick with calling classes by yourself :)

And you don't need the quotes around the word `blink`

Comment: hmm interesting, you switched from "red-whatever-red" animation to "whatever-red-whatever". So the problem was with the `background` definiton at `0%`? About the `nth-child(odd)`, it's an excellent suggestion, thank you. Last thing: how it's called such animation? Blink, to me, sounds more like "ON-OFF-ON-OFF", and not "ON-smooth transition-OFF-smooth transition ON"?

Comment: About the first question, yes, need to get rid of the `0% background` and about the on - off thing, didn't got it, are you asking for naming conventions?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation: it's nothing relevant, I was just wondering what's the correct "name" that you (native english ppl) use to refer that kind of thing: blink? glow? hypno-frog? etc etc

Comment: @BeNdErR oh, so we call as naming convention :) well, blink if fine, but if you are using as warning or say error, so you can be more descriptive, that `.error` or `.warning` :)